# Get notified if cmd.exe fails to successfully move a file?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.3-rio

I run cmd.exe to move a file with Administrator rights:

```
ThisParams := '/C move ' + '"' + ThisSourceFile + '"' + ' ' + '"' + ATargetFile + '"';
Winapi.ShellAPI.ShellExecute(0, 'runas', 'cmd.exe', PChar(ThisParams), '', Winapi.Windows.SW_HIDE);
```

Unfortunately, `ShellExecute` always gives back success, regardless of whether the **move** action was successful or not (the move action would fail for example if the target file exists and it is read-only or if the target disk is write-protected).

So how can I get notified if the **move** action in the above case fails?

Comment: You can't. `ShellExecute` launches the command interpreter. Clearly, that operation succeeds. `ShellExecute` cannot notify you about the outcome of operations launched on its behalf. You're going to have to look for another solution (like writing your own file-move program, and launching that instead).

Comment: You should stop trying to use `cmd.exe` to move files, and do that from your own code. I see that you are wanting to elevate, but you will need to address that issue another way. The `runas` verb isn't the right solution here.

Comment: Couldn't I use `try-except`? What kind of error occurs if `MOVE` fails? OS error? Win32 error?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The `runas` verb is used for another purpose, it has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: The `runas` verb is used to elevate. If you don't need to elevate you can just call the `MoveFile` API function to perform the move.

Comment: use `CoGetObject`  with `"Elevation:Administrator!new:{3ad05575-8857-4850-9277-11b85bdb8e09}"` for get elevated `IFileOperation` - it show uac promt if need. than use `IFileOperation`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3273064/505088

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why do you still always downvote my questions? Is this an emotional issue?

Comment: Does the [`MoveFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefile) API work for you?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I need to move the file with Administrator rights without the calling app having any, so the move action has to be performed by a different process because an app cannot elevate itself.

Comment: The link above shows you how to do it without explicitly invoking another process, using the COM elevation moniker. This works beautifully.

Comment: Ok, got it. Have you checked the link as @David Heffernan pointed out. Feel free let me know if there is any issue.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps you can use pipes and the load generated file
ex. move A.txt B.TXT >result.txt

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  stToDo: string;
  sl1 : TSTringList ;
  MyResult : boolean ;
begin
  stToDo := '/C move "C:\Users\awr\Desktop\D2\a.txt" "C:\Users\awr\Desktop\D2\b.txt" >C:\Users\awr\Desktop\D2\Result.txt';
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'runas', 'cmd.exe' ,PChar(stToDo),'',  SW_HIDE);
  sl1 := TSTringList.create ;
  sl1.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\awr\Desktop\D2\Result.txt');
  MyResult := trim(sl1.text) <> '' ;
  sl1.Free ;
```

If the move fail "result.txt" is empty

Comment: What if this code attempts to load the file before it has been written?

Comment: Possible other solution: I could simply check whether the source file still **exists** after the cmd execution?

Comment: Use WaitForSingleObject to do it

Comment: Again not possible using `ShellExecute`. You'd need to use `ShellExecuteEx` and wait on the process handle.

Comment: @ALAINWEBER What handle should you pass to `WaitForSingleObject`?

Comment: Or an even better solution: If the target file exists: Compare the MD5 hashes of the source file and of the target file.

Comment: here you have an example - https://www.developpez.net/forums/d762772/environnements-developpement/delphi/langage/shellexecuteandwait-vista/

Comment: These all seem like terrible answers. @RbMm points the way correctly, and I added a link to an answer the gives a Delphi demonstration.

Comment: I don't see very much here that is obvious to me